# Error at urllib-- HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: yolov5

[Can anyone please give me solution of this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqZce.png)

Comment: Could you add more details, so people can understand the context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.